# Will we have whatever we wish in Jannah including worldly things like cars, private jets, yachts, tv, video games etc.?

Tags: jannah

Ive heard some imams say that we wont desire worldly things in Jannah. Is that really true?

Please reply if you have knowledge about it and got the time. I would appreciate it a lot

Comment: Ask yourself, in Jannah, what would you need cars or private jets for?

Answer (score 1):

Salam alaikoum, all praise be to Allah (swt),

There are many good fatawa regarding this including [this comprehensive one](https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/344242/dwellers-of-paradise-will-absolutely-have-what-they-desire) which should answer all of your questions. To put it simply, The Noble Quran states that Jannah "will have whatever [those who inhabit Jannah] desire, and with Us is ˹even˺ more" and you will have "whatever your souls desire, and there you will have whatever you ask for" (Surah Qaf 31 and Fussilat 31).

Once you are confronted of the unimaginable beauty of Jannah, I somehow doubt that your first wish will be for a private jet.

May you InshaAllah reach Jannah so you can find your answers first-hand,

And Allah knows best.

Answer (score -1):

While you may get the things you mentioned, **you will not get whatever you wish** -

- You can't wish people who have been admitted into hell to move to paradise (there is an option for intercession during judgement, but once judgement is delivered you can't wish that to be reverted. So if a near one to you is in hell, they remain in hell for the appointed term)
- You can't wish to move to a higher level of Jannah. If you are in the lowest level and wish to move to the highest level, that's not gonna work. Of course, you may visit residents of higher levels.
- You can't wish harm to other residents of Jannah. In fact, your mind will be cleansed in such a way that you won't be able to think about anything evil anymore.
- You can't wish for things that infringes upon other residents will. For example, you can't wish to have another residents partner.
- It should be obvious, you can't wish for anything that compromises the divinity of Allah. For example, you can't wish to become all-powerful.

There may be more cases, but these are the things I can think of from the top of my head.

Comment: To the people who downvoted this - it would be great if you pointed out the problem with the answer in comment.